# Stuggling with PosrgreSQL trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

In `PostrgreSQL`, I have two tables as shown below

**Table_1**

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | lmn |
| 2 | def | opq |
| 3 | ghi | rst |

**Table_2**

| id | name | fk_table_1_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 |
| 2 | ghi | 3 |

I want to create a `trigger` which would update only that record of `Table_1`  when the `name` of a row in **Table_2** is Updated. My following `SQL` is hanging the PostgreSQL and the associated webapp

```
// Trigger Function Definition
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_table_1_func()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_1 SET name = table_2.name from table_2 WHERE table_1.id = table_2.fk_table_1_id;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE ‘plpgsql’;

// Trigger Definition
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS table_1_update_trigger_on_update ON “table_2”;
CREATE TRIGGER table_1_update_trigger_on_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON “table_2”
            EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_table_1_func();
```

The above appears to be updating all records. And since the webapp is active with several users accessing and updating the values in **Table_2**, the system is getting stalled due to several events of trigger.

Is there a way with which only the Updated row of **Table_2** would trigger updation of **Table_1** row?  I could not understand the concept or method of using `WHEN OLD <> NEW`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UPDATE` should only modify the row in `table_1` that corresponds to the modified row in `table_2` (available via `NEW`):

```
UPDATE table_1 ... WHERE table_1.id = NEW.fk_table_1_id;
```

To keep the trigger from firing if the `name` is not changed, add a `WHEN` clause to the trigger that only fires if the `name` before and after the update are different:

```
... WHEN (OLD.name IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.name)
```

Comment: Can you please re-write my code as I am not able to achieve what you advised

Comment: The better path for you would be to read the documentation and the examples there. With some deeper understanding and the pointers in my answer, this should be easy.